# Why is SlimbookBattery not availbale for Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: tlp

I want some GUI for TLP, and none of them (TLPUI, Slimbook) have the release files for 23.04 of Ubuntu. When can I expect it, or is there any workaround this?

Comment: Install the LTS version?  Versions from an LTS will likely work for all intermediate releases.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** I'm not sure I understand your question. Ubuntu 23.04 is a new release, so many applications are not yet available (this is why @Rinzwind suggests that you install an LTS release of the OS). However, why not [reach out directly to the Slimbook Battery team](https://github.com/Slimbook-Team/slimbookbattery)? From my quick read of open issues, there's no mention that this application can't be installed on 23.04. But again, I'd suggest you contact them directly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is not available, because nobody has packaged it. Slimbook tends to package for LTS releases, so if nobody else does it, it is not expected that it will be packaged for 23.04.
Your alternative would be to compile it yourself.

https://github.com/Slimbook-Team/slimbookbattery